# IdentityServer4 implicit grant acr values

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect, identityserver4

I am trying to pass tenant id as parameter to identityserver4 implicit grant end point. The client is written using angularjs, are there any examples to pass the tenantid from angular app to identityserver4 end point.

I have found that this feature was implemented using acr_values. More details are here - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes of course. you can always pass userID or any other variable in the state variable of your AUth request. if you include userID as a parameter in your request URL when sending it to Auth server, it'll return the state to redirect URI. which means you'll have access to it there. the issue is when an implicit request is being sent, it practically detaches your app from server cause the response URI (possibly) is in a different state/page. so by passing it as in state, the authorization server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back to the client.

```
public Authenticationrequest() {
var client_id = "YOUR-CLIENT-ID"; 
var scope = "OPTIONAL"; 
var redirect_uri = "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI"; 
var response_type = "token"; 
var authserver = "YOUR-AUTH-SERVER-URL?"; 
var state = "OPTIONAL"; // put UserID here
var AuthenticationURL = authserver + "response_type=" + response_type + "&scope=" + scope + "&client_id=" + client_id + "&state=" + state + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri; 
return AuthenticationURL; 
};
```